# SQLite3 regexp performance

Tags: sqlite

How performant is the SQLite3 REGEXP operator?

For simplicity, assume a simple table with a single column `pattern` and an index

```
CREATE TABLE `foobar` (`pattern` TEXT);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `foobar_index` ON `foobar`(`pattern`);
```

and a query like

```
SELECT * FROM `foobar` WHERE `pattern` REGEXP 'foo.*'
```

I have been trying to compare and understand the output from `EXPLAIN` and it seems to be similar to using `LIKE` except it will be using regexp for matching. However, I am not fully sure how to read the output from `EXPLAIN` and I'm not getting a grasp of how performant it will be.

I understand it will be slow compared to a indexed `` WHERE `pattern` = 'foo' `` query but is it slower/similar to `LIKE`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sqlite does not optimize `WHERE ... REGEXP ...` to use indexes. `x REGEXP y` is simply a function call; it's equivalent to `regexp(x,y)`. Also note that not all installations of sqlite have a `regexp` function defined so using it (or the `REGEXP` operator) is not very portable. `LIKE`/`GLOB` on the other hand can take advantage of indexes for prefix queries provided that [some additional conditions are met](https://sqlite.org/optoverview.html#like_opt):

> 1. The right-hand side of the LIKE or GLOB must be either a string literal or a parameter bound to a string literal that does not begin with a wildcard character.
> 2. It must not be possible to make the LIKE or GLOB operator true by having a numeric value (instead of a string or blob) on the left-hand side. This means that either:
>      the left-hand side of the LIKE or GLOB operator is the name of an indexed column with TEXT affinity, or
>      the right-hand side pattern argument does not begin with a minus sign ("-") or a digit.
>      This constraint arises from the fact that numbers do not sort in lexicographical order. For example: 9<10 but '9'>'10'.
> 3. The built-in functions used to implement LIKE and GLOB must not have been overloaded using the sqlite3_create_function() API.
> 4. For the GLOB operator, the column must be indexed using the built-in BINARY collating sequence.
> 5. For the LIKE operator, if case_sensitive_like mode is enabled then the column must indexed using BINARY collating sequence, or if case_sensitive_like mode is disabled then the column must indexed using built-in NOCASE collating sequence.
> 6. If the ESCAPE option is used, the ESCAPE character must be ASCII, or a single-byte character in UTF-8.

Comment: If I understand correctly, regexp scans the entire table and calls `regexp(pattern, 'foo.*')` to find matches?

Comment: Correct. You can also see that with `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN`.